# Script execution stops at os.execlpe()

Tags: python

I am a bit of a newbie on Python, but was was testing some things I learned on Ubuntu.
Basically, this script is supposed to set your TCP/IP config, then restart the networking daemon and display the changes.

This is the whole script:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
import commands
import os
import sys

euid = os.geteuid()
if euid != 0:
    print "Script not started as root. Running sudo.."
    args = ['sudo', sys.executable] + sys.argv + [os.environ]
    # the next line replaces the currently-running process with the sudo
    os.execlpe('sudo', *args)

print 'Running. Your euid is', euid

print "IP"
IP = raw_input(">>")
print "Gateway"
PE = raw_input(">>")

ifconfig = commands.getoutput("ifconfig")
interfaz = ifconfig[0:5]

ArchivoInterfaces = open("/etc/network/interfaces", "w")
ArchivoInterfaces.write("#auto lo\n#iface lo inet loopback\nauto %s\niface %sinet static\naddress %s\ngateway %s\nnetmask 255.255.255.0"%(interfaz, interfaz, IP, PE))
ArchivoInterfaces.close()

ArchivoResolv = open("/etc/resolv.conf", "w")
ArchivoResolv.write("# Generated by NetworkManager\ndomain localdomain\nsearch localdomain\nnameserver 8.8.8.8\nnameserver 8.8.4.4")
ArchivoResolv.close()
os.execlpe('/etc/init.d/networking', "test","restart", os.environ)
print "Todo esta correcto, su IP ahora es %s" %(IP)
fin = raw_input("write d and press enter to show the changes, or press enter to exit.")

if fin == "d":
    ArchivoResolv = open("/etc/resolv.conf")
    ArchivoInterfaces = open("/etc/network/interfaces")
    ifconfig2 = commands.getoutput("ifconfig")
    print "ARCHIVO resolv.conf\n"+ArchivoResolv.read()+"\n\n"+"ARCHIVO interfaces\n"+ArchivoInterfaces.read()+"\n\n"+"RESULTADO DE \"ifconfig\"\n"+ifconfig2
    fin = raw_input("Presiona ENTER para salir.")
```

Unfortunately, it keeps stopping on this line - and I'm not sure why:

```
os.execlpe('/etc/init.d/networking', "test","restart", os.environ)
```

After reaching this spot, the script runs the restart, and then just exits.

I would love to get it to run the last part of the script so I can see what changed, but I'm unable. Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because all of the `exec` family of functions work by replacing the current process with the one you execute.

If you just want to run an external command, use the `spawn` functions instead. (In this case, `os.spawnlpe` is very nearly a drop-in replacement.)

Comment: Ok i will test it, thank you for the fast answer, anyway im just curius now, why in the first os.execlpe('sudo', *args) that i run, it continue my whole script?

Comment: Because it is working correctly -- it is relaunching your script under `sudo`. There's no need to continue after that point.

Answer (score 0):

[`os.execlpe`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/os.html#os.execlpe) (and the similar os.exec* functions) replace the current process:

> These functions all execute a new program, **replacing** the current process; **they do not return.**

Comment: Ok i will test it, thank you for the fast answer, anyway im just curius now, why in the first os.execlpe('sudo', *args) that i run, it continue my whole script?

Comment: @adrian.py Because the new executable is your script (again) that time. So it's replacing your script with `sudo` yourscript. If you put a print on the first line of your script, you'll see that it gets called twice if you don't run it as root (once before the sudo, then again after).